# How to add textview and editview inside custom listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to create a custom listview of the following format. for example

```
 _______________________________________
|                                       |
| -----------           ------------    |
|  Principal              EditView      |
| -----------           ------------    |
|                                       |
| -----------           ------------    |
|  Years                  EditView      |
| -----------           ------------    |
|                                       |
| -----------           ------------    |
|  Rate of Int             EditView     |
| -----------           ------------    |
|_______________________________________|

 _______________________________________
|                                       |
| -----------           ------------    |
|  Interest               EditView      |
| -----------           ------------    |
|_______________________________________|

 _______________________________________
|                                       |
| -----------           ------------    |
|  Simple Int             EditView      |
| -----------           ------------    |
|_______________________________________|

 _______________________________________
|                                       |
| ------------          ------------    |
|  Compond Int            EditView      |
| ------------          ------------    |
|_______________________________________|
```

in-short the item1 in listview should contain 3 text and editviews and item2 should have 2 text and editview. both item should get different input.

since i am new to android, i was able to create simple listview, but i have no idea how to create a listview with various views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a custom adapter, this adapter will be able to inflate its own xml view for each cell.

your new xml view should simple have the most complicated layout that your listview will use, and for each cell that doesn't use information for a subview, simply set that subview to invisible.

this should at least guide you in the right direction

Comment: @Allen Maybe you'll find this link useful http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Why are you planning to use a `ListView`? A `TableLayout` combined with a `ScrollView` might be an easier option for you.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me to make an own ArrayAdapter.
There you get the methode

getView()
which you may overwrite.

There you use the 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
to inflate your own view which you have defined as XML in your layouts.
You can than Fill the view elements directly in this method.

In my code I made a Layout of an Icon, two text fields and a ProgressBar. Looking like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 ... >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/inventory_item_icon"
        .../>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inventory_item_titel"
        .../>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inventory_status_textfield"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inventory_item_info"
        ... />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/inventory_item_status"
        ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After it was simple to fill them directly in getView()
My code looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory_icon_text_text, parent, false);
TextView textViewTitel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.inventory_item_titel);
TextView textViewInfo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.inventory_item_info);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.inventory_item_icon);

textViewTitel.setText(values[position]);
  String s = values[position];
    if (s.equals("A")) {
       imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
       textViewInfo.setText("This is case A!"); 
    } else if (s.equals("B")) {
    return rowView;
}
```

So you can directly address the individual View elements.
If you want to have different View Layouts, you may try to check this before you inflate your layout. Thank you can chose which one you want to use.

Hope this helps you!
 Tobias